# Certificate for Gitlab-Server is invalid für Subject Alternative Name

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, gitlab, subject-alternative-names

My company has a certificate for https://data.ddl.at, which has, among others, a SAN (Subject Alternative Name) for `gitlab.ddl.at`.
This Gitlab-Server is internal, and the domain name is only resolved by our internal DNS-Server.
For reference, there is also the SAN https://sicher.ddl.at, which is public, and is valid in a browser.

I have configured this certificate on the Gitlab-Server, and when I go to `gitlab.ddl.at`, the certificate is validated by the browser and considered valid.

The problems arise, once I try to use a Gitlab-Runner.
I have one installed and registered on another machine, and after having some problems at first, I got it to connect to the main instance, but the jobs still cannot check-out submodules, the runner is getting `server certificate verification failed`.

Now here for what I believe to be a root symptom of the problem:
If I run `openssl s_client -connect data.ddl.at:443`, I get:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R3, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G3
verify return:1
depth=0 businessCategory = Private Organization, serialNumber = FN 374566h, jurisdictionC = AT, jurisdictionL = Wels, jurisdictionST = Oberoesterreich, C = AT, ST = Oberoesterreich, L = Ruestorf, street = Erwin Greiner-Str. 4, OU = GIS, O = DDL GmbH, CN = data.ddl.at
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:businessCategory = Private Organization, serialNumber = FN 374566h, jurisdictionC = AT, jurisdictionL = Wels, jurisdictionST = Oberoesterreich, C = AT, ST = Oberoesterreich, L = Ruestorf, street = Erwin Greiner-Str. 4, OU = GIS, O = DDL GmbH, CN = data.ddl.at
   i:C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G3
 1 s:C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G3
   i:OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R3, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
---
Server certificate
[...]
```

And at the end: `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`

Now when I run `openssl s_client -connect gitlab.ddl.at:443`, I get:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=0 businessCategory = Private Organization, serialNumber = 374566h, jurisdictionC = AT, jurisdictionL = Wels, jurisdictionST = Oberoesterreich, C = AT, ST = Oberoesterreich, L = Ruestorf, street = Erwin Greiner-Stra\C3\9Fe 4, OU = GIS, O = DDL GmbH, CN = data.ddl.at
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 businessCategory = Private Organization, serialNumber = 374566h, jurisdictionC = AT, jurisdictionL = Wels, jurisdictionST = Oberoesterreich, C = AT, ST = Oberoesterreich, L = Ruestorf, street = Erwin Greiner-Stra\C3\9Fe 4, OU = GIS, O = DDL GmbH, CN = data.ddl.at
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:businessCategory = Private Organization, serialNumber = 374566h, jurisdictionC = AT, jurisdictionL = Wels, jurisdictionST = Oberoesterreich, C = AT, ST = Oberoesterreich, L = Ruestorf, street = Erwin Greiner-Stra\C3\9Fe 4, OU = GIS, O = DDL GmbH, CN = data.ddl.at
   i:C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G3
---
Server certificate
[...]
```

With the first error being `unable to get local issuer certificate`.

I have also tried this with the publicly accessible `sicher.ddl.at`, with the same error as `gitlab.ddl.at`.

The certificate it gets is for `data.ddl.at`, but it has the SAN `gitlab.ddl.at`, shouldn't this make it valid? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the server at `gitlab.ddl.at` is missing the issuer certificate.

If the client and server do not have the proper root and intermediate certificates then you can run into validation errors.

I always make sure to install the full chain on the server to make sure all clients can get all certificates in the chain.

You have a couple of options.

1. Export the full chain from `data.ddl.at` and then import it to `gitlab.ddl.at`.
2. Use a tool like OpenSSL to combine the chain into one certificate then install to `gitlab.ddl.at`
3. Install all the certificates in the chain to the server.

Comment: Option number 1 was my solution, once I had the entire certificate chain in the CRT-File and restarted the server, the error was gone. Thanks a lot @AutoGnome!